# image gallery code?

Tags: iphone

is there any code available for image gallery??

i want to make a gallery in which,first view will show thumbnails of images and on selecting any of the images,it will come up in full screen...something like dat?

suggestions are always appreciated.
regards
shishir

Comment: i m new in here, i dont hv ny idea, how to cope up here.
thanks for the advice...will keep in mind.

Comment: Should this be an webpage or a perhaps a desktop application? What language are we talking about? Please add some info so that we can help you.

Comment: i want create image gallery for iphone application.